# Comparing a value of one table to a range in another

Tags: excel

[image]

So I have a table with a value in column A and columns B and C contain a range (lower and upper bounds). I want to use this table to compare to another sheet in excel that has a value within those ranges. So say Table A has a value of 88, I need to be able to compare this value of 88 to the table in the picture before. So it should be 15.0 as the output. I've tried several different VLOOKUPS and INDEX/MATCH formulas but haven't been successful.

Comment: Use `SUMIFS`....

Comment: @BigBen, wouldn't I have to make a criteria for every single range? That would be a bunch of criteria requirements and get messy, no?

Comment: If you have Excel 365 look into the new `FILTER` function

Comment: Not if you use `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: @BigBen I guess I'm just not following. Are you able to provide a formula of how you'd be doing it with 'SUMIFS'

Comment: If your lookup value (88) is in cell D1, then `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&D1,C:C,">="&D1)`